# Does Highcharts support Controls and Dashboard like in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-visualization

I'm swinging between [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) to visualize my data. I like the charts produced by Highcharts, but I wonder whether Highcharts supports features like the [Controls and Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls?hl=en) in Google Charts.

Below is a demo of how controls and dashboard in Google charts look like. If you run the code snippet, you can see two controls (a range slider and a gender filter) and two charts (a pie chart and a table chart). We can use the slider and filter to control how charts are displayed.

Can Highcharts do something like this? I didn't seem to find any related documentation. If it can, any sample code would be much appreciated.

```js
       // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
        'packages': ['controls']
      });

       // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

       // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
       // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
       // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael', 'Male', 12, 5],
          ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
          ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
          ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
          ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
          ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
          ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8]
        ]);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
          }
        });

        // Create a category filter for gender
        var genderFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'cfilter_div',
          'ui': {
            allowMultiple: false,
            labelStacking: 'vertical'
          },
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Gender'
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          },
          'view': {
            'columns': [0, 3]
          }
        });

        var tableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'table_div'
        });

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, [pieChart, tableChart]);
        dashboard.bind(genderFilter, [pieChart, tableChart]);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="filter_div"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="cfilter_div"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="table_div"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It can. All objects are addressable in highcharts via jQuery (at least). So, using a slider to set age filter (like in demo) and drop down to select gender are all doable. You just need to write the code to do so. Is there are specific question you had regarding a specific implementation of an item?

Comment: Yes, you can create nearly any interaction you want, you just have to write the event handlers and tell highcharts what to do. jQuery UI can handle the controls themselves.